# Formatting of \pi

Tags: fonts, greek, letters

Does anynone know how to obtain this kind of fonts in LaTeX (both text and math):

[image]

I can reproduce most of these but I can't reproduce style of pi letter very well. I know that these fonts are TeXGyre Thermes with txfonts for math, but it seems that something else has been also used.

Many thanks,

Radek

Comment: That `\int` (and the main font) looks like `newtxfonts`, but I'm not sure that exact `\pi` is the one you will get.

Comment: /pi is not from newtxfonts... I tried.

Comment: do you have that document in electronic form, or just on paper?

Comment: Just a paper... I contacted the author and got the details above. She told me she used raw TeX but no very much details (she had a company and this means some secrets...). I know in addition that some AmsTeX might be used, but I didn't find such pi symbol in it. Some other greek letters are also different than default ones.

Answer (score 8):

For me it looks very much like the `pi` from `TeX Gyre Termes`:

[image]

So it was perhaps obtained for TeX Gyre Termes+ `unicode-math` (newtxmath loads Nimbus for maths).

Here is an example with `unicode-math`. Actually, `TeX Gyre Math Termes` doesn't use an upshape π from `TeX Gyre Termes` text font, so I had to use a `\text` command.

Also, it doesn't have a `\mathcal` version like the default with Computer Modern, rapher something like `mathrsfs`. To get one, I had to resort to `MnSymbol`, which exists in opentype, using the `\setmathfont[range=\mathcal]{…}` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}%% additional symbols
\usepackage{unicode-math}[2002/01/22]

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[math-style=french,bold-style=TeX, vargreek-shape=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathcal{E} = \frac{1}{8\text{π}}\int(\mathbf{E}^2 + \mathbf{H}^2) \,\mathrm{d}V,\ \pi\neq\mathit{\pi}\neq\text{π}
\]

TeX Gyre Termes \verb+\mathcal+ is analogous to \verb+\mathrsfs+ script font, not to default’s TeX \verb+\mathcal+. To have on such font, we may use, say, \verb+MnSymbol+:
\[ \setmathfont[range=\mathcal]{MnSymbol}
  \mathcal{E} = \frac{1}{8\text{π}}\int(\mathbf{E}^2 + \mathbf{H}^2) \,\mathrm{d}V.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you got it. Maybe you should add a MWE.

Comment: I'll do that tomorrow (it's late now, and I don't know well unicode-math…)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg - The starting points and terminals of the "strokes" of `\uppi` in the OP's screenshot are either nicely rounded ("lacrymal") or smoothly tapered, whereas the starting points and terminals of the strokes of the glyph above have a distinctive "cut-off" quality. Thus, even though the two glyphs may be fairly similar in overall shape, that's not the case for the "character" or "quality" of the glyphs.

Comment: @Mico Good point; I didn't look at it that closely.

Comment: That's why I said it looks very close to. Anyway the magnification is not the same, and it's obtained with a font manager.

Comment: Many thanks. I tried to include unicode-math as a package but there is some error (sorry if this is a simple question...). What my preambule should look like to use all unicode-math, newtxtext and newtxmath (with a right order)?.

Comment: I tried: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} \usepackage{unicode-math} \usepackage{newtxtext} \usepackage{newtxmath}` but with some error messages (! Package unicode-math /b/c9/cError:/b/c0/c Cannot be run ). I use MiKTeX 2.9 with Led and try to compile to PDF.

Comment: @Radek You need (Xe|Lua)LaTeX to use `unicode-math` package.

Comment: @Bernard What about the MWE? `:)` It looks like new users could use it.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Done!

Answer (score 5):

The `newtxmath` package provides `\uppi` as well. (`newtxtext`/`newtxmath`, `txfonts`, and `TeX Gyre Termes` are all clones of `Times Roman`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathcal{E} = \frac{1}{8\uppi}\int(\mathbf{E}^2 + \mathbf{H}^2) \,\mathrm{d}V,\ \pi\ne\uppi
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{upgreek}

\newcommand*\diff[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d} #1}
\newcommand*\field[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \varepsilon
  = \frac{1}{8\uppi} \int (\field{E}^{2}+\field{H}^{2}) \diff{V}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: It's very similar but not quite exactly like this. For example, left leg is slightly different:)

Comment: It's good:) I'm really thankful, but perhaps someone will recognize this even further:) If not, I will use your suggestion obviously.