# How to properly use TeX Gyre Termes

Tags: tex-gyre-math

The last topics appeared to be my partial questions on something more general... From my research and extensive help from other users (like Bernard) I managed to use `newtxmath` and `newtxtext` packages in formatting of my simple document.

I would also like to use the `\pi` as presented here:

[Formatting of \pi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248472/formatting-of-pi/248483#248483)

Bernard pointed out that such `\pi` is from the `TeX Gyre Termes` family:

http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/tex-gyre/qtm-info.pdf

However, I am completely unable to use it. My current (very simple test) document preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
This is text: $\int$ $y$, $\pi$.
\[\int y \pi\]
\end{document}
```

But this does not provide the fonts presented in the linked PDF above (namely `\pi` symbol).

I try to use MiKTeX 2.9 with Led editor. Many thanks for helping.

Radek

Answer (score 3):

Note that the TeX Gyre Termes math fonts, which are OpenType, are only available for Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX (yet?). You have to switch to one of these engines if you want to use them.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}
The $\pi$ number.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see. Any tips / procedures how to proceed with such switch using MiXTeX and Led?

Comment: @Radek I know very little of Windows and I never used MikTeX nor Led, so I can't be of any help for this…

Comment: OK. Managed to transfer to XeLaTeX:) But now I have some problems with using `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` in text and equations, but these `TeX Gyre Termes` fonts for greek letters. The I specify `\usepackage{unicode-math} \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}` math font change considerably.

Comment: @Radek The newtx math fonts are type 1 (PostScript) and have not the same design as the TeX Gyre Termes math fonts. It is not recommended to mix them. You should make a choice between both…

Comment: Though I bet it is possible to make such mix:) I would in general like to use newtx math but with some selected symbols from TeX Gyre Termes.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145382/9075 for a discussion that TeX Gyre Termes Math does not produce that good results.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to load `tgtermes` separately, I don't think, as `newtxtext` uses those fonts anyway. But you do need to tell `newtxmath` that you want upright Greek:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[uprightGreek]{newtxmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  This is text: $\int$ $y$, $\pi$.
  \[\int y \pi\]
\end{document}
```

[image: upright Greek]

With `frenchmath` you get upright Greek but also some other things you might not wish:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  This is text: $\int$ $y$, $\pi$.
  \[\int y \pi\]
\end{document}
```

[image: frenchmath]

With no options, you can still access the upright pi using `\piup`:

[image: 2 pi]

Or you can make just this the default i.e. just affect this symbol using `\let\pi\piup`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\let\pi\piup
\begin{document}
  This is text: $\int$ $y$, $\pi$.
  \[\int y \pi \piup\]
\end{document}
```

[image: pi pi pi]

Comment: I tried but the result is identical when using or not using the `[uprightGreek]`. Also the `code` is not from the original `TeX Gyre Termes` family.

Comment: @Radek Do you want just the pi upright? Or all the Greek? For some reason, the package only uses upright Greek generally with the French maths spacing option... Otherwise, you get some upright Greek, but it is a limited set. You can use `\piup` for upright pi. Do you want just to access it or have it be what you get with `\pi`?

Comment: @Radek See edits for some possibilities.

Comment: I would like to use all the symbols exactly like in http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/tex-gyre/qtm-info.pdf. For example pi has been identified by user Bernard as 03C0 (page 10), but I'm completely unable to use these fonts and formatting style.

Comment: @Radek Sorry, but that doesn't make sense. There are, for example, 4 pi symbols for that point in unicode. `\pi` will produce one of them, at least within any given context. You can have it produce the upright one or the italic one by default. I don't understand why you say you can't use the fonts or the style. Your MWE uses the fonts. And my answer shows how to access the upright pi in various ways. (The edited version, that is.)

Comment: But these are not exacly as used in this PDF file describing the `TeX Gyre Termes`. I think about the first of the pi symbols, but this applies for all greek letters.

Comment: @Radek I think `newtxmath` uses its own fonts for the Greek letters rather than taking them from Termes. The pi specifically is in one of the TG encodings but many Greek letters are not. So it wouldn't really make sense to use those which are for maths, given that they would not match the rest. For example, the epsilon does not appear to be available at all. This means that accessing those glyphs would require creating new support files to supplement those provided. That is doable but it is time-consuming and fiddly work. If Xe/LuaTeX are options, there are more possibilities, of course.